# How to build a scalable stream server, to handle and broadcast to millions of users?

Tags: java, react-native, networking, video-streaming, live-streaming

I'm planning to make a game like Trivia HQ and i know it isn't so simple. I wanted to know the possible solutions to build a scale-able server to handle around 5 to 10 million users on the same country. This is what i've planed but i'm not sure it will work or not.

1: App will be created in react-native (because i'm pretty familiar with this and it is a cross-platform).

2: Will create an admin panel to publish questions in the game.

3: Handle all the questions and answers using firebase realtime database and admin portal.

4: Record a video and send it to the server through RTMP encoder.

**Questions**:

I can broadcast these packets to the users but, Can I show RTMP Packet directly to the app or i've to convert it before sending and showing to the app?

Should i make a server in node js and use socket io for broadcasting **(Already done some messaging app but not for too much traffic, not sure single threaded nodeJs will work or not)** or have to use some other libraries? or completely use other technology like java or something else for server side?

Or there is a better solution to make this?

Please let me know if you didn't get. Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: You can always create sharding wrappers around your sockets but as far as I recall the socket.io performs slow when the user count and traffic increases substantially like in your case. Its probably not suitable for your work.

Comment: thanks @UmutGüler. So what you suggest me? Do you know about WOWZA it creates an RTMP link to integrate in app or Youtube, Facebok etc. Do you know how can i make something like that or should i use tcp for send data from server?

Comment: To be honest except socket.io problems that I have encountered while I was building a 300 user application. I didn't use anything that is enough scalable for your solution. But regarding Socket.io like I said a sharding solution may help a little bit but will require too much work further down the road as you need a lot more scalable product comparing to Socket.io. So tldr; as for suggestion I am not sure, except the fact that socket.io is probably not your solution.

Comment: Broadcasts are limited to the local network. Routers will not forward broadcasts. You must be using unicast. You cannot broadcast or multicast across the public Internet.

Comment: Use a proper CDN.  Hire people who know how to do this.  Those are the only answers if this is truly the scale you're going after.  (Are you sure this is the scale you need?  Hint:  Probably not.)

Comment: You know, there's another way... television.  If you expect that much traffic, you should have no trouble signing on with a network.

Comment: Yes @Brad i'm pretty sure this is the scale i need. BTW - thanks for you comments.